# Non split extension isomorphic (as a group) to a split extension

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, group-cohomology

$\def\Z{\mathbb{Z}}$
Let $A$ be a finite abelian group and $G$ a finite group acting on $A$.
Then the extension $0 \to A \to E \to G \to 1$ is splits if and only if the corresponding $2$-cocycle is trivial in $H^2(G,A)$.

Does there exist such a split extension $E$ such that $E$ can also be seen as a non split extension (for the same action of $G$ on $A$)? Or in other words, can we find two groups $G$ and $A$, and an action of $G$ on $A$ such that there exists $\alpha_1,\alpha_2 \in H^2(G,A)$ which corresponds to the same group $E$, and with $\alpha_1=0$?

With help from user [gro-tsen](https://mathoverflow.net/users/17064/gro-tsen), I can say the following:

- In the answer here:
  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131881/group-extensions/131895#131895
  one can find two extensions of $G=(\Z/p\Z)^2$ by $A=(\Z/p\Z)^2$, isomorphic as groups, and one splits and the other not. Unfortunately the action by $G$ on $A$ is different, so this does not quite answer my question.
- In the answer here: [Extensions isomorphic as groups but not congruent or pseudo-congruent](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35649/extensions-isomorphic-as-groups-but-not-congruent-or-pseudo-congruent/35662#35662) one can find that there exist non pseudo congruent extensions (but isomorphic as groups), even for the trivial action, even for an abelian extension $E$. But in this example none of the two extensions split.
- In fact if $E$ is abelian, it can't be both a split and a non split extension of $G$ by $A$. This is a special case of
  [Can a module be an extension in two really different ways?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42174/can-a-module-be-an-extension-in-two-really-different-ways/42309#42309)

Comment: More generally than the abelian case, J. Ayoub proved that a finite group that is a direct product $A\times B$ cannot be written as a non-split extension of $A$ by $B$.

Comment: @Robinson: but $(\Z/2\Z) \times A_5$ is not isomorphic as a group to $SL(2,5)$, no?

Comment: I can think of examples in which $A$ and $G$ are infinite. At the moment I would not like to bet either way on whether there exist finite examples.

Comment: @YvesCornulier: Where did Joseph prove this?

Comment: http://user.math.uzh.ch/ayoub/PDF-Files/DIRECT.PDF (J. Ayoub, The direct extension theorem. J. Group Theory 9 (2006), 307-316.)

Comment: About an easy infinite example: Let $A$ be the product (of order 8) of cyclic groups of order 2 and 4. Let $G$ be the (restricted or unrestricted) direct product of countably many copies of $A$. Then $G$ is isomorphic to $G\times G$ and can also obviously be decomposed as a non-split extension  of $G$ by $G$.

Comment: @Yves yes, that was (almost) exactly the example I had in mind!

Comment: @Geoff Robinson We want a finite group $E$ with two isomorphic abelian normal subgroups $N_1$ and $N_2$ such that: (i) $E/N_1$ and $E/N_2$ are isomorphic groups and, using this isomorphism,  $N_1$ and $N_2$ are equivalent modules under the actions induced by conjugation; and (ii) $N_1$ has a complement in $E$ but $N_2$ does not.

Comment: @Yves: thanks for the reference! There is another infinite example here http://mathoverflow.net/a/42184/26737

Comment: I did some experimental testing with Gap, and (barring errors in my code) I've ruled out the existence of examples with the order of $E$ being, or, of course, dividing, one of: 128, 192, 288, 160, 240, 360, 400 or 336.

Comment: Perhaps this approach is useful.  Assume that $B$ is a subgroup of $G$ which is isomorphic to $A$ as a $G$-module, such an isomorphism can be extended to an isomorphism $\phi : A \rightarrow B$ of $E$-modules. This induces an isomorphism between the abelian groups $Der(E,A)$ and $Der(E,B)$ in the obvious way.  I wonder if $\phi$ induce a ring isomorphism or more generally if there is a ring isomorphism between $Der(E,A)$, $Der(E,B)$.  If so Then $E$ splits over $B$. (The multiplication in $Der(G,A)$ is the  composition of map)